# How can I reduce the space above the title of a single chapter

Tags: spacing

I am using a thesis template. And now my abstract is override 1 single page. I found the space before the chapter title is quite large. However, I just want to reduce such a space in the abstract chapter rather than every chapter. I have searched but no good choice for my purpose.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper,twoside]{memoir}
        % *************** Document de style ***************

    % *************** chargement des packages ***************

% euh, je ne sais pas plus ce que ça donne :/
\usepackage{etex}

% paquets d'encodage des caratères
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} % à changer    05202015
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[cyr]{aeguill}

% ensemble de paquets pour "franciser" le documents
\usepackage[frenchb,english]{babel}
\selectlanguage{english}
\frenchbsetup{GlobalLayoutFrench}
\FrenchFootnotes
\AddThinSpaceBeforeFootnotes
\usepackage{frbib}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{textcomp}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Customized here
\usepackage{slashbox, pict2e}    % added on 01022014
\usepackage{lscape}              % added on 02102014 for large table
\usepackage{rotating}            % the same purpose as the above

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%ensemble de paquets pour afficher des maths
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{bbm}

% paquets pour tableaux, figures...
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table,hyperref]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}            % added on 19112013
\usepackage{colortbl,hhline}  % added on 20112013 for tabular
%\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption} % added on 20112013 for tabular
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{algorithm}        % added on 04282014
\usepackage{algorithmic}      % added on 04282014
%\usepackage{subfigure}        % added on 05152014
%\usepackage{subfig}        % Added on Oct. 21, 2014.
\usepackage{url}              % added on 05152014

%\usepackage{titlesec}         % added on 05202015 for chapter title

%\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
%%\usepackage[acronym,nomain]{glossaries}   % added on 05182015
%\makeglossaries

%\usepackage{chngcntr}
%\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}




% pour avoir des paragraphes justifiés correctement
\usepackage{microtype} 

% pour faire des "cholies" figures
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations,backgrounds,shapes}


\usepackage{ifpdf}
% pour citer des adresses web
\usepackage{url}

% fixe la taille du documents
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    body={150mm,230mm},
    left=30mm,
    top=35mm,
    headheight=7mm,
    headsep=9mm,
    marginparsep=4mm,
    marginparwidth=27mm}


% a changer suivant la version (définitive ou pour relecture ^^)
\def\baselinestretch{1.2} % simple interligne
%\def\baselinestretch{1.56}  % double interligne

% comme con nom l'indique
\fixpdflayout


% pour utiliser des lettrines (premiere lettre en grand ^^)
\usepackage{lettrine}
\newcommand{\malettrine}[2]{\lettrine[lines=2, lhang=0.33, loversize=0.25]{#1}{#2}} % format de la lettrine
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\color [gray]{0.5}} % couleur de la lettrine

% *************** Permet d'ajouter la page des citations dans la biblio ***************
\usepackage{citeref}
\renewcommand{\bibitempages}[1]{\newblock {\scriptsize [\mbox{cité p.\ }#1]}}


% *************** Pour avoir des liens dans le pdf ***************
\ifpdf
    \pdfcompresslevel=9
        \usepackage[plainpages=false,pdfpagelabels,bookmarksnumbered, %
        colorlinks=true, % impression -> false // en ligne -> true % important pour le nombre de page couleur ! ca coute chere !
        linkcolor=Sepia, %
        citecolor=Sepia, %
        filecolor=Maroon, %
        urlcolor=Blue, %
        pdftex, %
        unicode]{hyperref} 
    \pdfimageresolution=600
\else
    \usepackage{hyperref}
\fi


% pour gérer des 'todo', très utile pour les corrections
\usepackage[french]{todonotes}


%pour corriger des incompatibilités entre 'mémoire' et 'hyperref'
\usepackage{memhfixc}

% pour les minitables en début de chapitre
\usepackage[french]{minitoc}

% *************** Style des chapites et sections ***************

% voir la ref du 'memoire' pour plus d'info
% permet de changer le style des titre de chapitre, section, paragraphes...

\chapterstyle{bianchi}

\setsecheadstyle{\Large\sffamily\bfseries}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\large\sffamily\bfseries}
\setsubsubsecheadstyle{\normalfont\sffamily\bfseries}
\setparaheadstyle{\normalfont\sffamily}


\makeevenhead{headings}{\thepage}{}{\small\slshape\leftmark}
\makeoddhead{headings}{\small\slshape\rightmark}{}{\thepage}


\setafterparaskip{1ex plus .5ex}



% *************** Style de la table des matières ***************
%indique la profondeur du contenu de la talbe des matières
\setsecnumdepth{subsubsection}
\maxsecnumdepth{subsubsection}
\settocdepth{subsubsection}
\maxtocdepth{subsubsection}    
% modified on 21112013, all 4 ori are {subsection}



% *************** Style de minitoc ***************
% idem pour minitoc
\setcounter{minitocdepth}{1}



% ********** Epigraphes **********
% gestion de la commande epigraph
\setlength{\epigraphwidth}{0.87\textwidth}
\setlength{\epigraphrule}{0pt}
\setlength{\beforeepigraphskip}{1\baselineskip}
\setlength{\afterepigraphskip}{0\baselineskip}

\newcommand{\epitext}{\raggedleft\sffamily\itshape}
\newcommand{\epiauthor}{\sffamily\scshape ---~}
\newcommand{\epititle}{\sffamily\itshape}
\newcommand{\epidate}{\sffamily\scshape}
\newcommand{\episkip}{\medskip}

\newcommand{\myepigraph}[4]{%
    \epigraph{\epitext \raggedleft #1\episkip}{\epiauthor #2\\\epititle #3 \epidate(#4)}\noindent}

% *************** Autre ***************
% divers...

% un style de list personalisé...
\newenvironment{malist}
{ \begin{list}%
    {$\bullet$}%
    {\setlength{\labelwidth}{30pt}%
     \setlength{\leftmargin}{35pt}%
     \setlength{\itemsep}{\parsep}}}%
{ \end{list} }

% je ne sais plus pourquoi... pour corriger une erreur...
\newsubfloat{figure}

% \bf non géré par 'memoire', donc...
\renewcommand{\bf}{\textbf}

% pour avoir des guillements francais bien géré
\renewcommand{\og}{\og\xspace} % ouverture 
\renewcommand{\fg}{\fg\xspace} % fermeture

% pour faire des note (avec paquets todonotes), suffit de faire \note{sjhfjshfhfjh} pour que ca s'affiche sur fond vert clair
\newcommand{\note}[1]{\todo[inline,color=green!40]{#1}}

% raccourcie, pour citer Truc \etal 
\newcommand{\etal}{\emph{et coll.}\xspace} % et en francais, c'est et coll., pas et al.

% pour "francisé" les pages d'annexe
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Annexe}
\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Annexe}

% pour changer l'affiche des titres des figures
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\fnum@figure}[1]{\figurename~\thefigure~-- \sffamily}
\makeatother



% *************** Fin du style ***************

\frontmatter
\input{abstract\abstract.text}

\mainmatter
%\input{chap1.tex}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There is no class mentioned, but knowledge of the class is required for a solution.

Comment: It's not universal to have a chapter-like heading for the abstract.  It may of course be required in your case, but often the abstract sits on a page of its own as part of the front matter -- i.e. before we get into chapters etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reduce the `\beforechapskip` locally:

```
{\addtolength{\beforechapskip}{-2\baselineskip}
  \chapter{Introduction}}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
{\addtolength{\beforechapskip}{-2\baselineskip}
  \chapter{Introduction}}
\Blindtext[3]
\chapter{Next Chapter}
\Blindtext[3]
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If it's just in the abstract chapter, you can use a negative vspace before the chapter.

Comment: I have tried to use \vspace{-2cm} before the \chapter*{...} but doesn't change it.

Comment: The code you posted was only the document class.

Could you show the code of the part of the document where you want this space to be reduce ?

Comment: The one after the \frontmatter.

Comment: It is simply 
\chapter*{Summary}
\markboth{SUMMARY}{SUMMARY}

\thispagestyle{empty}
text text ....